# Не могу подключить dll к проекту msvs

Tags: visual-studio, dll

Вроде делаю все по инструкции, но при выполнении всё равно не находит dll
Вот, такие настройки выставил, dll в папке проекта находится. А по итогу freeglutd.dll он не видит, только если в system32 бросить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: exe будет видеть dll только рядом с самими exe, либо в папке, добавленной в переменную окружения PATH (в том числе, в system32).

Comment: @insolor
Понял, спасибо. А зачем тогда все эти пути было прописывать?

Comment: Для компиляции нужно, чтобы линкер знал, где лежит файл статической библиотеки freeglut.lib (может как-то по-другому называться), чтобы прилинковать код из него в готовый exe файл. Если не указать, линкер не сможет собрать exe.

Comment: @insolor это да, я про то, зачем было прописывать пути к dll файлу, как это указано в инструкции на mdsn, если и без них все работает

Comment: Ну, если без них работает, то не прописывайте) Значит линкер и без этого знает их.